Container stockmgmt_0_3b1a53ce didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging. For Node js
"I am deploying a Node.js application using PM2 on an Azure App Service. The application appears to start successfully, but it fails the HTTP health check on port 8080, and the site does not start."
"The application should respond to HTTP pings on port 8080, allowing the App Service to start successfully."

Ensure you define your port as follows: const port = process.env.PORT || 8080; in your code.

If possible, share your code?

Can you connect and solve the issue ?

I Give linkedIn Connection

If you encounter any issues, please reach out here only.

I created simple Nodejs app with PM2 deployed to the Azure App service.
Even I got the same error when hardcoded the port value in the server.js and ecosystem.config.js.
Azure App Service expects the application to listen on the port specified by the PORT environment variable.
I define the port value as below
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;

server.js:
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello, World! Application is running.');
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${port}`);
});

ecosystem.config.js:
module.exports = {
    apps: [
      {
        name: "nodejs-app",
        script: "./server.js",
        env: {
          PORT: 8080
        },
        env_production: {
          NODE_ENV: "production",
          PORT: process.env.PORT 
        }
      }
    ]
  };

After successfully deploying the application, I set the following startup command in Azure Web App under Configuration -> Startup Command.
pm2 start ecosystem.config.js --no-daemon


Azure Web App Output:


I Do The Step But Samae Error Bro ?

@gokul dotech Are you still facing Application Error in default Azure Web app URL.

Yes I still Facing The Same Error

@gokul dotech Try setting the WEB_PORT : 8080 in azure web app environment variables.

@gokul dotech If the issue still persists try to deploy the application to new azure web app.
